# Associate a product to a record in own custom module

Tags: odoo-12

I'm new to odoo , i want to create a new product in the product module when a new record is created in my own custom module! how can i achieve this goal !?

by the way i'm using odoo v12

Answer (score 0):

Override create method of your custom model and created product in it.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(YouClassName, self).create(vals)
    self.env['product.product'].create({'name': 'Product1'})
    return res
```

Comment: If you want to associate custom model with product then use inherits. If you use inherits then when a record is created in your custom model then a product is also created and that product is linked with your custom model.

Comment: Can you explain how to use inherits to do this please

Comment: Add a many2one field in your custom model with product model and add inherits in your custom model.

Comment: _inherits = {'product.template': 'product_model_id'}    

product_model_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.template', 'Product Template',
        required=True)

Comment: thanks a lot it works even without using inherits but i used product.template

Answer (score 0):

Here is my create function :

```py
   @api.model
   def create(self, vals):
   res = super(GroupsalesGroupsales, self).create(vals)
       main_category = self.env['product.category'].search([])
          if main_category:
             main_category = main_category[0]
   self.env['product.template'].create({'name':  vals['name'],
                                        'categ_id': main_category.id,
                                      'list_price':vals['prix_rabais'],
                                      'default_code': 'GS-PROD',
                                'image_small' : vals['image_small'], })
  return res
```

Comment: ok, so you have a little bit of extra code.  You can write your if statement like this. `main_category = main_category[0] if main_category else 0`.  You can also do it this way and eliminate the initial search line. `main_category = self.env['product.category'].search([])[0] if self.env['product.category'].search([]) else 0`.

Answer (score 0):

When i try to add _inherits: {'product.product': 'product_id'} 
i get this error:
'ERROR:null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint'

Comment: may I ask why you're using _inherits instead of defining a field the normal way?